# Get to know my client ip in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have two tier app structure(Nginx(proxy)+nodejs(app).End of the day I need to get my client IP(who visited my site) in my application(nodejs). Now my client IP, it's getting logging in my Nginx log file (by enabling the below conf

```
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Now I am getting the Nginx server IP  in my app server, But I don't want to get my Nginx server IP, instead of that  I need to get my original client IP in my app

This is the app code, which we are using to get the client IP in 
app server.

```
request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.info.remoteAddress
```

Where;
Nodejs-- > Happijs framework

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943112/get-ip-user-with-nginx-and-node#30943228

Answer (score 1):

You should use below code :

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

If you are using Hapi framework then you should use below code:

```
var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.info.remoteAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION_SOURCE : [get ip user with nginx and node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943112/get-ip-user-with-nginx-and-node#30943228]),

You can configure NGINX to pass the client's IP address with the following setting:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://fotogena.co:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  # This line.
    proxy_connect_timeout   1000;
    proxy_send_timeout      1500;
    proxy_read_timeout      2000;
```

}

You can then use the HTTP header X-Real-IP from req.headers["X-Real-IP"].